# Can I keep controller in template file in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I have a Index page with following content:-

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div ng-view></div>
```

Below is my routing script:-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller  : 'homeController'
    }).when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    });
});
```

Can I keep the controller in templateUrl file? Like below:-

about.html

```
<script>
app.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is About Us page.';
});
</script>
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
```

Comment: Yes you can. But you need to make your template aware which controller it is associated with. Otherwise it would not find the code to run and throw errors

Comment: Not working, Can I have some example?

Comment: no, script in template files won't execute not to mention lazy loading controllers is not as simple as just including them later

Comment: If I have 200 controllers, so I need to add all of then in index page. It will overload the page. There must be a solution to keep all the files separate and they can be called while routing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can keep controller in template.

**index.html**

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
   <div ng-view></div>


  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'home.html',
          controller: 'homeController'
        }).when('/about', {
          templateUrl: 'about.html',
          controller: 'aboutController'
        });
    });
    app.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
      console.log("aboutController");
        $scope.message = 'This is about page.';
    });
    app.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
      console.log("homeController");
        $scope.message = 'This is Home page.';
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**home.html** and **about.html** I kept same

```
<h3> {{message}}</h3>
```

You can check demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lEHB6FW4X2AMlmuBLvt4?p=preview).

Comment: This not what I am looking for. You have kept all the controller in Index file. I want the controller to be in respective templateUrl. Like

'
app.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
      console.log("homeController");
        $scope.message = 'This is Home page.';
});
'
must be in home.html.

Comment: Still waiting for your reply @NetSonu